# creation of version file with rpm installation

Tags: java, maven, version, pom.xml, rpm

We have project called Proj. The rpm for it is generated through maven plug in.

(/home/user is a home directory)

Currently, the version file of the rpm is created in /home/user/Proj/version/Proj_ver.xml directory, and the symbolic link of it is created in /home/user/versions/Proj_ver.xml directory. **Now, we want to create original file (target file) in /home/user/versions directory with the same name Proj_ver.xml, and creation of symbolic link is not required.**

To achieve above, I am trying to find the point where the target version file is created. So I grepped for Proj_ver.xml in my Proj repository, but the only reference I found for that file is in .pmakes file (Proj/rpm/.pmakes). When I checked the .pmakes file, I figured out that this file creates only the symbolic link in /home/user/versions directory and not the original (target) file. Apart from this .pmakes file, nowhere else the Proj_ver.xml file is referred.

**Can somebody tell in how many ways rpm installation can create this version file (Proj_ver.xml) ? How do I figure out the point where this file is actually created in (/home/user/Proj/versions/Proj_ver.xml) ?**

Please note that when I comment the relevant lines which creates symbolink link from .pmakes file, it does not create any symbolic link for the version file (Proj_version.xml). Also the directory /home/user/Proj/version is specifiend in Proj/rpm/pom.xml under mapping tag. I am new to use of maven plugin for rpm creation.

Comment: These xml files are *in* the created rpm package (`rpm -qpl Proj-$ver-$rel.$arch.rpm` lists them)? Or those files are used by maven to build the rpm package?

Comment: @Etan Reisner : Yes, the files are created/contained in the rpm package. Although I could not run the commnad you specified, when I extract the rpm itself, I can see the version file in (/home/user/Proj/versions/Proj_ver.xml) which I actually want in /home/user/versions folder.

Comment: I'm assuming the build logs don't help you figure out what is creating that file in the first place? I'm also assuming that file doesn't exist in the sources directly? By "extract the rpm itself" you mean with `rpm2cpio` or `7-zip` or similar tool that unpacks the rpm (as opposed to `rpm` which installs it)? This sounds like it might be a maven issue (unrelated to rpm in which case I can't help much since I've never used maven.

Comment: yes Etan Reisner, I used rpm2cpio rpmfile | cpio -idmv command to unpack the rpm, and it shows me the version file in (/home/user/Proj/versions/Proj_ver.xml) which I want to avoid.

Comment: Can you get maven to dump the spec file it uses to build the rpm? Do the logs from the build say anything about this file anywhere?